# How do I open a link with a specific class within a jQuery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm trying to make 2 plugins work together on a wordpress site.  One is a sidepanel plugin that can be triggered by adding `class="nks_cc_trigger_element"`
to html `<a href="...">` link coding.

The other plugin is an image mapping plugin that will only let me set the URL of a link, and I need the `class` attribute set to have it trigger the sidebar by clicking one of the mapped shapes of the image.  The developers pointed me to the API with this code

```
$.imageMapProEventClickedShape = function(imageMapName, shapeID) {}
```

I have no experience with jQuery, and this seems like it should be a simple solution, but I'm lost.  The relevant `imageMapName` and `shapeID` are simple enough to find, but I don't know how to simply open a link with jQuery or append that link with a `class` attribute.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to use jQuery to set the class name of the link (anchor) tag? if so, is there an id attribute on it, or can one be set when the html is rendered?

Comment: Are you looking for $('#shapeid').click()?

Comment: I'm not even sure what I'm looking for exactly.  Here's what in the documentation:

`Customizing the Image Map using the API
Image Map Pro has an API that you can use to trigger various events on the image map. For example, you can have a tooltip open by default. Please read below for the full description of the API.`

Comment: `Events
Events are global functions, which are sent by the plugin when certain things happen. These functions need to be implemented by you, and you can put your own code inside them. Please see the example in the API-demo folder to see how the events are used in practice. The API-demo folder is located in the zip that you downloaded from CodeCanyon.`

Comment: So I think I need a code that can be put inside the `$.imageMapProEventClickedShape = function(imageMapName, shapeID) {}` function to open a link with the `class=nks_cc_trigger_element` class

Comment: @Aelliott1485 from inspecting element on page: `<div class="imp-shape imp-shape-rect" id="rect-2507" style="left: 0%;top: 0%;width: 74%;height: 100%;opacity: 0.5150375939849624;border-radius: 10px;background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5037593984962406);border-width: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" data-index="0"></div>`  so i think the ID attribute would be rect-2507 (the shapeID).

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/pirajo/6/edit?js,output

```
let a = document.querySelector("a");

if( a.classList.contains("hasClass") ){

    a.addEventListener("click",function(e){

        let link = this.getAttribute("href");

        window.open(link,"_blank");

        e.preventDefault();

    });

}
```